# Zabbix API trigger expression vs reduced trigger expression

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to use the Zabbix API to create a table with a list of hosts and their corresponding triggers. I am using trigger.get to build triggerid->itemid associations and host.get to  build hostid->itemid associations, and then join the two where itemid's match.

But from trigger.get, I can only get "description" (which is often not descriptive enough) and reduced trigger "expressions" (which are incomprehensible to me).

I need the full trigger expressions. Is there a way to get that from the API? Or is there a file where the reduced expressions are mapped to the full ones? Or perhaps some documentation online I might have missed? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `expandDescription` and `expandExpression` flags?

See [trigger.get API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/trigger/get) for all the supported flags.

Comment: Thank you! Setting "expandExpression":"True" is what I needed. I did look into the docs but had no idea what that part meant, and thus overlooked it, until your post.